# load and save PFFile to mongoDB

Tags: swift, xcode, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I am trying to get a PFFile from the MongoDB Database connected to a Parse Server instance hosted on Heroku.

I saved the file so (the file < 10mb):

```
var post = PFObject(className: "Posts")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "post_two")!, 0.5)

post["picImage"] = PFFile(name: "post_two.jpg", data: imageData!)
post["username"] = "example"
post["title"] = "welcome"
post["info"] = "Thanks"

post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool?, error:NSError?) in
                if (success != nil && success == true)
                {
                    print("post registred")
                }
                else{
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
```

and I loaded the post so:

```
let elements = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
elements.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error ==  nil
            {


                for object in objects!
                {
                    //add found data to arrays (holders)

              let imagesQuery = object.valueForKey("picImage") as! PFFile
              picArray.append(imagesQuery)


                }


            }

            else
            {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)! + "load post")
            }

 })
```

the problem is here:

```
picArray[i].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in



            if error == nil
            {

                picImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
            else
            {

                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }
        }
```

the error is : *Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 13.835050 seconds.
[Error]: unsupported URL (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0) unsupported URL*

In DEBUG the data in getDataInBackgroundWithBlock is NiL.  I do not know if the problem is the file storage, loading or App Transport Security Settings (in some post, some suggested to include exceptions domain, those I already inserted correctly, but nothing has changed ).

thanks a lot, I do not know where to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

On Parse server files are stored in the following way :
[SERVER_URL]/files/[APP_ID]/[YOUR_FILE]

For Parse "unsupported URL" correspond to NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL.
I think your URL contains some characters who must be percent escaped.
So your [APP_ID] or [YOUR_FILE] can contains characters not supported in the URL.

In general URIs as defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).
You can see here the [unreserved characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters)

You can get your url with the following way :

```
print(picArray[i].url)
```

And if you paste this url in a web browser it will percent escape for you.

Try to change your APP_ID in Heroku config variables.
And add it to AppDelegate.swift

With **old Swift** version:

```
    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "YOUR NEW APP ID"
        $0.server = "http://example.com/parse"
    }
    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

With **Swift 3**:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "YOUR NEW APP ID"
    $0.server = "http://example.com/parse"
}
Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
```

Sorry for my poor English,
I hope my answer was helpful